# My code has a "word is not define" error, please help, and please give me any other advice

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I was trying to make a hangman-like game. I just have an error with line 1 as I corrected my other errors. Also can you give me advice on what to use in the future/not to use, e.g. excess code. Here's the basic game;

```
word = hot
letters = ["h", "o", "t"] 
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess_count += 1 
    guess = int(input("What is your letter? "))
    if guess == letters[0]:
        print("One down!")
    elif guess == letters[1]:
        print("Holy Moly!")
    elif guess == letters[2]:
        print("Wow! you're on fire")
    if guess == word:
        if True:
            print("Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a winner!")
else:
    print("Better luck next time!")
```

It's my first project/game and also my first time on Stackoverflow, so please go easy on me, any advice will help me!

Comment: What you want is `word = 'hot'` (a string), as currently it thinks `hot` (without quotes) is a reference to another variable that you haven't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are some errors in your code:
**line 1:** `word = hot` ==> `word = 'hot'`. You need to set the value of the variable to a string, a string is declared with `' '` or `" "`. If you don't the compiler searches for the value of variable `hot`, which doesn't exist.
**line 7:** `guess = int(input("What is your letter? "))` ==> `guess = str(input("What is your letter? "))` or `guess = input("What is your letter? ")`. You prompt the player for letters, a `string`, so in your program you can either choose to use `str()` which converts the input to type `string` or you can choose to just use `input()` because this function returns a `string` value.
**general code** 
There are some improvements which you can make, shortening the `if - elif - elif` block:

```
# outside of while loop
correct = 0 
first = True
# after input() function in the while loop
if guess in letters: 
    correct+=1
    letters.remove(guess)
    print("You have found a letter!")
else:
    print("Wrong, try again")
if correct == len(word) and first == True:
    print("You have found all the letters")
    first = False
if guess == word:
    print("You have found the word!")
```

This should work. If you have any questions regarding this piece of code, feel free to ask. 
 **Challenge:**
 When the program asks for an input, make sure the number of the guess is shown. 
 e.g. `Guess 3, What is you letter?`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting `word = hot`. The compiler thinks that the word `hot` is refrence to another variable which is not defined so it throws a Undefined Variable Error/Exception.If the word `hot` is supposed to be a variable than define it before the `word = hot` line like this,

```
hot = 'Some Value'
word = hot
```

If hot is supposed to a string (word/sentence) then surround it with quotes i.e `word = 'hot'`

Comment: Thank you! have noted this down.

Comment: Note that unless you need the `hot` variable for any other use, you could just as well get rid of it and use `word = 'hot'` directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change:

```
word = hot
```

to

```
word = "hot"
```

Otherwise python will not recognise 'hot' as a string but instead will try to find the object representation of it within the current namespace.

Additionally you'll want to change the int cast to a str (for py2):

```
guess = int(raw_input("What is your letter? "))
```

to

```
guess = str(raw_input("What is your letter? "))
```

The user input will be a string, so trying to convert that input into an integer will cause an error!

Comment: If using py3, `input()` already returns a string so `str(input(...))` is redundant. If using py2, you should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, and then it's the exact same as py3 `input()`.

Comment: thank you for the correction! I corrected the integer(input.. also.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ah ok thank you - I was working on a python2 interpreter and seem to have mashed py2 and py3 in my answer. I will correct my code above for py2

Comment: @solarflare `str(raw_input())` is STILL redundant - `raw_input()` already returns a string.